# Excel baseline correction -formula use

Tags: excel, excel-formula

goal: use of a formula in excel that baseline corrects data and resets after every break in a column

- I am using microsoft excel and need to baseline correct the data in columns

-baseline corrected: use the first cell as the baseline and then compare the difference between the rest of the values in the column and the first cell.

I have gaps in between data and I need to reset the baseline scores whenever there is a new value to compare to.

So far, I wrote a quick formula of =first cell-B$first cell. For example in the screenshot below, I put in =b3-b$3. i then copied the formula by dragging to baseline correct from b6 to b7.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/efh3R.png)
What I do works but it doesn't work whenever there's a break in the data and also with a larger scale of data. I need to reset and write out the formula, which becomes tedious when dealing with a larger scale in data, which I need to do.

I've tried using the =IF formulas but have struggled to figure out one that resets after every break in data and then baseline corrects from the first cell of the new row. So for example, For p2 (b11-15), the baseline corrected value to compare from is 67, not 100 from p3.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a helper column that houses the baseline value.

I'm assuming that `FirstCell` is `B2`. In the helper column (same row as baseline) write a formula that uses the logic:

`If( isblank( [Cell above FirstCell]), [Firstcell], [CellAboveThis] )`

This will create a cellvalue for the firstcell after every break, then evaluate as normal. `=B3 - [HelperColumnCell]`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make that formula work and ended up having to code in excel to make it work. 

I do appreciate the help.